# hibernate native sql can't work but same query works good on sql developer

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I need your help.

I have to use native sql in case. Well, I started to write my query on sqldeveloper. This query works well on db. But I try on hibernate doesn't work my query.

The query is here (copied from Oracle Sql Developer):

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT ("Invoice"."amount")) AS totalAmount,
"MbsFile"."name","MbsFile"."surname",
"MbsFile"."oid" AS mbsFileOid,
"MbsFile"."investigationNumber",
"MbsFile"."subscriberNo",
"MbsFile"."identityNumber" FROM "Invoice" LEFT JOIN "MbsFile" ON "Invoice".MBSFILE_OID="MbsFile"."oid" LEFT JOIN "MbsFile_LawyerOffice" ON 
"MbsFile_LawyerOffice".MBSFILE_OID="MbsFile"."oid" WHERE "MbsFile_LawyerOffice".MBSFILE_OID IS NULL GROUP BY "MbsFile"."oid",
"MbsFile"."name","MbsFile"."surname","MbsFile"."investigationNumber","MbsFile"."subscriberNo","MbsFile"."identityNumber";
```

this work well(here is result).
[image]

But same query couldn't work on java, hibernate. I got errors.

Here is java code :

```
List result=null;
SQLQuery sqlQuery=null;
try{
    String sql = "SELECT " +
            "SUM(DISTINCT (Invoice.amount)) AS totalAmount," +
            "MbsFile.name," +
            "MbsFile.surname," +
            "MbsFile.oid AS mbsFileOid," +
            "MbsFile.investigationNumber," +
            "MbsFile.subscriberNo," +
            "MbsFile.identityNumber " +
            "FROM Invoice LEFT JOIN MbsFile ON Invoice.MBSFILE_OID=MbsFile.oid " +
            "LEFT JOIN MbsFile_LawyerOffice ON MbsFile_LawyerOffice.MBSFILE_OID=MbsFile.oid " +
            "WHERE MbsFile_LawyerOffice.MBSFILE_OID IS NULL " +
            "GROUP BY MbsFile.oid,MbsFile.name,MbsFile.surname,MbsFile.investigationNumber,MbsFile.subscriberNo,MbsFile.identityNumber";
    sqlQuery = currentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
 //   sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UnassignedMbsFileDTO.class));
    result = sqlQuery.list();
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I got this errors.

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
    at aras.law.hibernate.dao.invoice.InvoiceDao.getMbsFilesWillBeAssigned(InvoiceDao.java:112)
    at aras.law.resources.mbsFileLawyerOffice.MbsFile_LawyerOfficeResource.getAll(MbsFile_LawyerOfficeResource.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.UnitOfWorkRequestDispatcher.dispatch(UnitOfWorkRequestDispatcher.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.guava.OptionalResourceMethodDispatchAdapter$OptionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(OptionalResourceMethodDispatchAdapter.java:37)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:348)
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipFilter.doFilter(BiDiGzipFilter.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
    at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44)
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DefaultFilterPipeline.dispatch(DefaultFilterPipeline.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1097)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:175)
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.ContextRoutingHandler.handle(ContextRoutingHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: tablo veya görüntü mevcut degil

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 71 more
```

This  errors `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` and `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view doesn't exists`.

I tried to simple query here. `SELECT * FROM Invoice`. But result didn't change. I got same errors.

Could you explain what is the reason and help me please?

Comment: `"Invoice"` is a different table name than `Invoice` (see [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) for details) you need to teach your obfuscation layer (Hibernate) to use quoted identifiers. A better solution would be to **not** create tables with quoted identifiers in the first place

Comment: I can't get it. Could you give more detail please? How can I fix this?